# How to use -p flag in webpack from node-js api?

Tags: node.js, webpack

I have a script for my deployment which compiles modules for the entry points before running the webpack compiler. I would like to run the compiler with the -p flag using the node api (https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/node.js-api)
I can't see an option in the webpack config for this - is there one, or another way i can provide this argument to webpack?

Here is my script:

```
utils.runScript('node-scripts/generate-entries.jsx', ['--harmony'], (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('entries generated');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const webpackConfig = require('../webpack.config.js');
//want to add -p to this somehow
    webpack(webpackConfig, () => {
        console.log('deploy completed');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I was about to ask the same question. It looks like it's a new thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the Node API rather than the CLI, you need to set all options in your configuration object. The `-p` flag in the CLI activates [two plugins](http://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#production-shortcut-p):

1. [`webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#occurrenceorderplugin)
2. [`webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin)

You just need to make sure these are in your [plugins array](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-plugins.html) in your configuration object that you pass to `webpack({/* config */})`, like so:

```
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),
  new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(/* options */)
],
...
```

Comment: When using CLI wepback with -p flag it still produces 100kB lighter file than running it with these plugins